# How to get a datatype DF16_RAW with precision 16 by using CL_ABAP_ELEMDESCR for internal table in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I have internal type `A` for `DF16_RAW` and `E` for `DF34_RAW` and now at runtime I am creating a dynamic table for that I want datatype `DF16_RAW` and `DF34_RAW` with specified precision based on internal type. My code is like below:

```
CASE WA_COL-INTTYPE.
          WHEN 'A'.  LO_DESCR_RESULT = CL_ABAP_ELEMDESCR=>GET_DECFLOAT16( ).
          WHEN 'E'.  LO_DESCR_RESULT = CL_ABAP_ELEMDESCR=>GET_DECFLOAT34( ).
```

Here I want to get datatype with specified precision. I don't know how it be done?

Comment: why "java" and "database" tags?

Comment: You cannot create type with the precision *you want*, DF16_RAW has fixed precision and cannot be changed. If you database field has DF34_RAW precision and you receive only DF16_RAW then smth is wrong with your program and/or database, not with ABAP RTTS.

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of a variable are specific to the ABAP dictionary a.k.a. "DDIC" (search help, [output style for the DF* types](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenddic_decimal_floating_point.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENDDIC_DECIMAL_FLOATING_POINT_2), etc.) If you want to create one variable with information specific to the ABAP dictionary, then you must refer to an element in the DDIC (i.e. a data element or table/structure component), then use:

```
lo_descr_result = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'DDICdataelement' ).
```

or

```
lo_descr_result = cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_name( 'DDICtablestruct-Component' ).
```

Comment: Thank's for reply but i am getting following error:                            
The result type of the functional method cannot be converted into the type of LO_DESCR_RESULT. type of LO_DESCR_RESULT

Comment: Actually in sap table i have data in df34_raw format with 34 precision but at runtime while storing in dynamic table it is coming with precision 16 only.

Comment: @ompalshekhawat I guess your first question about the type is now solved, as I can see you could get a little bit further as shown in your second question

Comment: @ompalshekhawat in fact I misunderstood your initial question, you need to debug your program. Moreover, you tested 'A' and 'E' in uppercase, while the internal values of decimal floating point Numbers are 'a' and 'e' in lowercase, so maybe that answers your question.